# Use RegEx to uppercase and lowercase the string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to convert a string to uppercase and lowercase based on the index.

My string is a `LanguageCode` like `cc-CC` where `cc` is the language code and `CC` is the country code. The user can enter in any format like "cC-Cc". I am using the regular expression to match whether the data is in the format `cc-CC`.

```
var regex = new Regex("^[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
//I can use CultureInfos from .net framework and compare it's valid or not. 
//But the requirement is it should allow invalid language codes also as long 
//The enterd code is cc-CC format
```

Now when the user enters something `cC-Cc` I'm trying to `lowercase` the first two characters and then `uppercase` last two characters.

I can split the string using `-` and then concatenate them.

```
var languageDetails = languageCode.Split('-');
var languageCodeUpdated = $"{languageDetails[0].ToLowerInvariant()}-{languageDetails[1].ToUpperInvariant()}";
```

I thought can I avoid multiple strings creation and use `RegEx` itself to uppercase and lowercase accordingly.

While searching for the same I found some solutions to use `\L` and `\U` but I am not able to use them as the `C#` compiler showing error. Also, `RegEx.Replace()` has a parameter or delegate  `MatchEvaluator` which I'm not able to understand.

Is there any way in `C#` we can use `RegEx` to replace uppercase with lowercase and vice versa.

Comment: .NET regex does not support case modifying operators. Yes, use `MatchEvaluator`. `Regex.Replace(s, @"(?i)^([a-z]{2})-([a-z]{2})$", m => $"{m.Groups[1].Value.ToLower()}-{m.Groups[2].Value.ToUpper()}")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh thanks for the information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.NET regex does not support case modifying operators.

You may use `MatchEvaluator`:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?i)^([a-z]{2})-([a-z]{2})$", m => 
    $"{m.Groups[1].Value.ToLower()}-{m.Groups[2].Value.ToUpper()}");
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/8hQPNT).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - the inline version of `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` mopdiofier
- `^` - start of the string
- `([a-z]{2})` - Capturing group #1: 2 ASCII letters
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([a-z]{2})` - Capturing group #2: 2 ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I have a doubt though is Regex faster than individual string replacement?

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa If you need to both validate and fix, a regex is OK, IMHO. If you know users cannot input anything other than 2 ASCII letters, `-`, and again 2 ASCII letters, sure, use a mere [`string.Join("-", s.Split('-').Select((x,i) => i % 2 == 0 ? x.ToLower() : x.ToUpper()))`](https://ideone.com/nIIWWl) or anything like that.

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa: Ignore faster and go for what is most readable. The average coder is going to spend a lot longer trying to work out what this regex replace is doing compared to your original split method.

Comment: Both perspectives are true. I will add this question link as a comment so that next developer will come to know why it's used. :-)

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR: This is Regex.Replace with \U and \L support.

```
    private static string EnhancedReplace(string input, string pattern, string replacement, RegexOptions options)
    {
        replacement = Regex.Replace(replacement, @"(?<mode>\\[UL])(?<group>\$((\d+)|({[^}]+})))", @"<!<mode:${mode}>%&${group}&%>");
        var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, options);
        output = Regex.Replace(output, @"<!<mode:\\L>%&(?<value>[\w\W]*?)&%>", x => x.Groups["value"].Value.ToLower());
        output = Regex.Replace(output, @"<!<mode:\\U>%&(?<value>[\w\W]*?)&%>", x => x.Groups["value"].Value.ToUpper());
        return output;
    }
```

## How To Use

#### Call the function with \U followed by the group to be uppercase

```
var result = EnhancedReplace(input, @"(public \w+ )(\w)", @"$1\U$2", RegexOptions.None);
```

#### Will replace this:

```
public string test12 { get; set; } = "test3";
```

#### With that:

```
public string Test12 { get; set; } = "test3";
```

## Details

I'm currently working on an app which allows the user to define a batch of Regex Replace operations.
For example the user enters json and the batch converts it to a C#-Class.
Therefore, speed is no key requirement. But it would be very handy to be able to use `\U` and `\L`.
This method will apply Regex.Replace 3 times to the whole content and one time to the replacement string. Therefore it’s at least three times slower than Regex.Replace without `\U` `\L` support.

### Step by Step

1. The first `Regex.Replace` enhances the replacement string.
   It replaces: `\U$1` with `<!<mode:\\U>%&$1&%>`
   (Also works for named groups: `${groupName}`)
2. The new replacement will be applied to the content.
3. & 4. The inserted placeholder is now relatively unique. That allows you to search only for `<!<mode:\\U>%&Actual Value&%>` and use the MatchEvaluator to replace it with its uppercase version. The same will be done for `\L`

### Regex101 Demo:

Step 1: Enhance pattern with placeholder
https://regex101.com/r/ZtqigN/1

Step 2 Use new replacement pattern
https://regex101.com/r/PWLTFD/1

Step 3&4 Resolve new placeholders
https://regex101.com/r/5DIIUo/1

## Answer

```
var result = EnhancedReplace(input, @"(cc)(-)(cc)", @"\L$1$2\U$3", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: The best practice would be to check if the content contains the placeholder in the beginning. If so, you should escape the placeholder so there will be no error. But I don’t think it’s worth the time because the placeholder is pretty unique.